# How do I call a C++ function from C# using inout parameter

Tags: c#, c++

I am creating a WPF application using the Sony Camera Remote SDK and am able to load the SDK C++ DLL and initialise it by calling the library functions.

Now I am trying to enumerate the USB devices by calling a function that requires a pointer to a C++ class.

If there any way to do this from C# - there seem to be a number of different ways of interacting with C++ libraries from C#.

This is the C++ function call I am trying to use but I am not sure how to create or access the `ICrEnumCameraObjectInfo` class from C#, if this is even possible.  I am sure I cam across one approach where a proxy C# object is created and passed to the C++ function call but I can't seem to find that reference now.

```
SDK::ICrEnumCameraObjectInfo* camera_list = nullptr;
    
auto enum_status = SDK::EnumCameraObjects(&camera_list);
```

And these are the classes involved

```
class ICrCameraObjectInfo
{
public:
    virtual void Release() = 0;
    // device name
    virtual CrChar* GetName() const = 0;
    virtual CrInt32u GetNameSize() const = 0;

    // model name
    virtual CrChar *GetModel() const = 0;
    virtual CrInt32u GetModelSize() const = 0;

    // pid (usb)
    virtual CrInt16 GetUsbPid() const = 0;

    // device id
    virtual CrInt8u* GetId() const = 0;
    virtual CrInt32u GetIdSize() const = 0;
    virtual CrInt32u GetIdType() const = 0;

    // current device connection status
    virtual CrInt32u GetConnectionStatus() const = 0;
    virtual CrChar *GetConnectionTypeName() const = 0;
    virtual CrChar *GetAdaptorName() const = 0;

    // device UUID
    virtual CrChar *GetGuid() const = 0;
    
    // device pairing necessity
    virtual CrChar *GetPairingNecessity() const = 0;

    virtual CrInt16u GetAuthenticationState() const = 0;
};

class ICrEnumCameraObjectInfo
{
public:
    virtual CrInt32u GetCount() const = 0;
    virtual const ICrCameraObjectInfo* GetCameraObjectInfo(CrInt32u index) const = 0;

    virtual void Release() = 0;
};
```

And I have a C# class to wrap this:

```
 class SDK
    {
        [DllImport("crsdk\\Cr_Core.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern long GetSDKVersion();

        [DllImport("crsdk\\Cr_Core.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern bool Init();

        [DllImport("crsdk\\Cr_Core.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern bool Release();


        [DllImport("crsdk\\Cr_Core.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern bool EnumCameraObjects(IntPtr cameraInfo);


}
```

EDIT:
I found a reference where there seems to be a way of creating a C# managed object that can be used - obviously a different class used in the example below.  Is it possible to create something like this to represent the two C++ classes above ?  And if so what would they look like?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class StatClass
    {
        public uint DeviceID;
        public uint InodeNumber;
        public uint Mode;
        public uint HardLinks;
        public uint UserID;
        public uint GroupID;
        public uint SpecialDeviceID;
        public ulong Size;
        public ulong BlockSize;
        public uint Blocks;
        public long TimeLastAccess;
        public long TimeLastModification;
        public long TimeLastStatusChange;
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.usb.usbdevice?view=winrt-22000

Comment: I am not trying to interact with USB devices directly.  I am calling the Sony SDK library functions.

Comment: If the SDK has a `tlb` type library then you can create a .NET Interop Assembly for it, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/how-to-generate-interop-assemblies-from-type-libraries. There might be some tool that can construct a `tlb` out of the `.h` C++ header files, I think `midl.exe` can do this